# Can Flink statefun application run on a Flink session cluster?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

Can I run a Flink statefun application on an existing Flink session cluster? The docs in older statefun versions (2.2) said it was possible, but that part has been removed from docs in newer versions, so wondered if it is still possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Statefun 2.0 document (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.0/deployment-and-operations/packaging.html#flink-jar) provides instructions to package and deploy a statefun job in a jar to an existing flink cluster.  Is this mode still possible? That is, to package statefun 3.1 jar and deploy as a job to an existing Flink 1.13 cluster?  If so, where to put the module.yaml file?